# Shell script - proper quoting in the awk command

Tags: awk, quotation-marks

I have a awk command with 2 parameters and one condition - if it is fullfilled, it returns second parameter. So far, it looks like this and works well

```
awk -v PARAM_NAME="user" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":") { print $2;}}'
```

Now, I would like to add one check and see if the second parameter ends with a certain character. I know that, in order to read the last character of $2, I need to read it like this.

```
echo "${2: -1}"
```

The problem is - I dont know how to escape those double quetes properly (or at least thats where I think the problem lies). This is what I have now, could someone tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you

```
awk -v PARAM_NAME="user" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":" && "${2: -1}" == "\"","\"") { print $2;}}'
```

Whole command

```
cf env some-odata-app | grep "\"hana\":" -A 30 | awk -v PARAM_NAME="user" -v lastchar="${2: -1}" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":" && lastchar == ",") { print substr($2, 2, length($2)-3);}}'
```

Expected input after first two commands. I want to get both password and user, cleared from quotes. So need to know if to cut two or three characters from the end

```
"hana": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {  
     "password": "obfuscated",
     "schema": "oiuhjoiuhyupoihj",
     "url": "pkpokpokp[kjpo[kpo",
     "user": "USER"
    },
 
  ]
```

Comment: Passing shell variables to `awk` should be `awk -v var="$shell_variable" '{....}'` could you please do add more details what you are trying to achieve so that we can get better understanding of your question here as its not clear in your question.

Comment: Hello, this is how the whole command looks like. It gets env variables from Cloud Foundry and tries to clear quotes, the problem is that the last one in the json doesnt end with coma so the last character gets cut when parsing it. Just trying to determine the last character for now, then will need to handle both scenarios -> cf env hana-cloud-analytics-odata-app | grep "\"xsuaa\":" -A 30 | awk -v PARAM_NAME="xxx_param" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":" && "${2: -1}" != "\"","\"") { print substr($2, 2, length($2)-3);}}'

Comment: it would be a bit easier to understand the requirements if you could update the question with sample inputs and desired output (corresponding to the sample inputs)

Comment: ok, updated - tried to reduce the question as much as possible, maybe it wasnt a good idea :)

Comment: and what is the expected output? `USER` and `obfuscated` on separate lines? the two values on a single line and with a delimiter (white space? comma? colon?)? do you need to capture these 2 values into variables in the calling shell script, or just print to stdout?

Comment: just one value - script runs twice, once for user, second time for password - desired column is submitted as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of the question appears to have changed from 'passing shell parameters into awk' to 'pulling last character from a awk variable/field' to 'parsing out the user and password from a cf/grep command batch'.

Sample data generated by the `cf/grep` command batch:

```
$ cat hana.dat
"hana": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {  
     "password": "obfuscated",
     "schema": "oiuhjoiuhyupoihj",
     "url": "pkpokpokp[kjpo[kpo",
     "user": "USER"
    },
   ]
```

OP wants to run 2 separate commands, one to extract the `user` and one to extract the `password`.

One `awk` solution that uses the double quote as the input field separator:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v PARAM_NAME="user" '$2 == PARAM_NAME { print $4 }' hana.dat
USER
$ awk -F'"' -v PARAM_NAME="password" '$2 == PARAM_NAME { print $4 }' hana.dat
obfuscated
```

---

Keep in mind we can also pull both values via a single `awk` call, eg:

```
$ awk -F'"' '$2 == "password" || $2 == "user" {print $4}' hana.dat
obfuscated
USER
```

One `grep/cut` idea that emulates the `awk` solution:

```
$ grep -E 'password|user' hana.dat | cut -d'"' -f4
obfuscated
USER
```

**NOTE**: Will likely need to reformat the output depending on how OP plans to capture and use these values.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect - and works well. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

OP can add a second `-v` flag to pull in the last character of a shell variable, eg:

```
awk -v PARAM_NAME="xxx_param" -v lastchar="${2: -1}" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":" && lastchar == "\""e"\"") { print $2;}}'
```

If the objective is to find the last character of an input field we can use a combination of the `length()` and `substr()` functions, eg,

```
$ awk '{ print substr($1,length($1),1) }' <<< 'STUVWXYZ'
Z
```

Comment: Brilliant! Good idea to get it before the actual command starts. Just one last question - what if I want to compare not e character, but for example coma?

Comment: Not sure I understand ... is the last character a `comma`? or are you looking to compare the last character to see if **it** is a `comma`?

Comment: I want to compare the last character, to see if its a coma

Comment: `awk -v lastchar="${2: -1}" ' .... if (lastchar == ",") ...'` or `awk ' ... lc=substr($1,length($1),1) ; if ( lc == ",") ... '`

Comment: cool, thats unexpected - no need to "escape" the coma, like "e" character

Comment: no need to escape the `comma` ; not sure why you're looking to escape the letter `e` ... ?